# How can I check in multiple files in SharePoint 2007 without admin access?

Tags: sharepoint

I have files in a few folders that I add to SharePoint every day. I currently have to browse to each folder in turn, and use the menu to check in each file in turn. This is a laborious and slow process.

I heard there is a way to do this via the site administration, but as a non-administrator, is there a way I can check in all my pending files?

If not, is there a way to add multiple files and check them in, in a single step?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is how you'd do it if you can get to the Site Administration under site actions:

Site Actions>>Manage Content and Structure>>View:Checked out to me>>Slect items and check in

OR

Site Actions>>Under Site Administration>>Manage Content and Structure>>View:Checked out to me>>Slect items and check in

https://kis.kellogg.northwestern.edu/Pages/SharePointMassCheckIn.aspx

You should be able to get to the "Manage Content and Structure" even if you were just a sharepoint member user.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question, I'm not an admin and won't be getting admin rights.

Comment: Dont quote me on this but I dont think you'd need admin rights to get to the Manage content and structure page.